# Geo.PostGIS: "undefined function fragment/3"

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm having trouble using [Geo Elixir package](https://github.com/bryanjos/geo). Here are the steps to reproduce the error.

I added the package to the dependency and `iex -S mix` to test it out.

```
iex(1)> import Geo.PostGIS
iex(2)> geo1 = %Geo.Point{coordinates: {49.2769578,-123.1219351}, srid: 4326}
iex(3)> geo2 = %Geo.Point{coordinates: {49.2759393,-123.1215435}, srid: 4326}
iex(4)> st_distance(geo1, geo2)
** (CompileError) iex:4: undefined function fragment/3
    expanding macro: Geo.PostGIS.st_distance/2
    iex:4: (file)
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure `st_distance` can only be used in PostgreSQL queries as the calculation is done by PostGIS which depends on PostgreSQL. `st_distance` will only work in Ecto queries.

Answer (score 0):

> All of the functions in the `Geo.PostGIS` module, such as
>   `st_distance/2`, can only be used inside `Ecto.Query` syntax. So you
>   use it inside queries and not to work directly with the data types.

(https://elixirforum.com/t/geo-postgis-undefined-function-fragment-3/1708)